# Does Eclipse have any cache or the like or settings that can get corrupted

Tags: eclipse

Does Eclipse have any persistent settings (that can get corrupted).

All of sudden my eclipse is doing strange things -- java programs won't run (though I can run them fine from the command line).

If there is such a things -- how do I purge it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, such things can indeed happen (I just had a screwed up workspace because I ran out of disk space).

In the workspace, look for the `'.metadata'` folder. Tread carefully, but e.g. usually all the plugin-local configs in `'.plugins'` can safely be removed. You'll just loose some settings.

Hope it helps!

PS: By the way, for your concrete problem, what's the actual error you are getting?

Comment: Hi ShiDoiSi, Thanks for the solution -- I set the language version to 1.6 and I think I don't have the compiler for it -- when I bring up the properties dialog it is broken. BTW deleted .metadata -- still no can do -- on OSX leopard -- using Version: 3.7.1 of eclipse -- once again thanks for the help. Cheer!

Comment: That's unusual; the dialog shouldn't really break ;) Can you upload a screen shot? Is there anything in the Error Log (Window -> Show View)?